# Jspdf e canvas responsivo

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf

Estou a gerar PDF com `jspdf` e faço o screenshot com o `canvas`. O `form` que gera o PDF é muito grande e gera mais do que uma página.
Código:

```
window.html2canvas = html2canvas; 

function demoFromHTML() { 

const html_source = document.getElementById('employee_detail'); 
const filename = 'PIC.pdf'; 

html2canvas(html_source).then(function(canvas) { 

let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); 
let imgWidth = 210; 
let pageHeight = 297; 

let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width; 
let heightLeft = imgHeight; 
let position = 0; 
let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm'); 
let fix_imgWidth = 0;  
let fix_imgHeight = 18;

pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight); 
heightLeft -= pageHeight; 

while (heightLeft >= 0) { 
position = heightLeft - imgHeight; 
pdf.addPage(); 
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth + fix_imgWidth, imgHeight + fix_imgHeight); 
heightLeft -= pageHeight; 
} 
pdf.save(filename); 
}) 
}
```

O problema é que quando gero o pdf no pc, faz a quebra de página corretamente, mas quando faço gerar o pdf no telemóvel já faz a quebra de página incorreta.
Como posso colocar o meu código de forma a ajustar a quebra de página sempre correta independentemente do tamanho do ecrã?

Deixo aqui o link para visualizarem a quebra de página no telemóvel:
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eRgni_NPfpx0qwPANKEeHJbTBl07Aj_f/view?usp=sharing)

Aqui deixo o link do mesmo pdf em computador:
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MTk1AKeJjBhSrRLEYe0OhhvWLO8qlz0h/view?usp=sharing)

Queria que imprimisse onde imprimisse ajustasse o documento à tela do equipamento automaticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possível solução:

- Busca o ponto de interrupção do dispositivo (*[Device Breakpoints](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp)*);
- Através do `if/else` ponderar a quebra da tela de acordo com o dispositivo.

Ou seja, tens que configurar o seu código de acordo com a largura de cada tela.

**Existem toneladas de telas e dispositivos com diferentes alturas e larguras, por isso é difícil criar um ponto de interrupção exato para cada dispositivo. Para manter as coisas simples, você pode segmentar cinco grupos comuns:**

> - *Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down)*
> - *Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up)*
> - *Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up)*
> - *Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up)*
> - *Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up)*

**Exemplo:**

```
const deviceWidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;

window.html2canvas = html2canvas;

function demoFromHTML() {

  const html_source = document.getElementById('employee_detail');
  const filename = 'PIC.pdf';

  html2canvas(html_source).then(function(canvas) {

    let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    let imgWidth = 210;
    let pageHeight = 297;

    let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
    let heightLeft = imgHeight;
    let position = 0;
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');

    let fix_imgWidth = 0; // Padrao
    let fix_imgHeight = 18; // Padrao


    if (deviceWidth < 600) { //  max-width: 600px -  Dispositivos extra pequenos

      fix_imgWidth = 0;
      fix_imgHeight = 18;

    } else if (deviceWidth > 600) { // min-width: 600px - Pequenos dispositivos

      fix_imgWidth = 0;
      fix_imgHeight = 18;

    } else if (deviceWidth > 768) { // min-width: 768px - Dispositivos médios

      fix_imgWidth = 0;
      fix_imgHeight = 18;

    } else if (deviceWidth > 992) { // min-width: 992px  - Dispositivos grandes

      fix_imgWidth = 0;
      fix_imgHeight = 18;

    } else if (deviceWidth > 1200) { // min-width: 1200px - Dispositivos extra grandes

      fix_imgWidth = 0;
      fix_imgHeight = 18;

    }


    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;

    while (heightLeft >= 0) {
      position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
      pdf.addPage();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth + fix_imgWidth, imgHeight + fix_imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    }
    pdf.save(filename);
  })
}
```

E obviamente o `fix_imgHeight` e o `fix_imgWidth` vais ajustar de acordo com a tela.

Comment: no telemóvel continua sem fazer a quebra de página correta.

Comment: Meu caro Jovem, tens que alterar os valores  `fix_imgHeight` e `fix_imgWidth` de acordo com a resuloção da tela. Usa o emulador do navegador para simular vários tipos dispositivos. Abrir emulador no Chrome: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I` e depois  `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `M` e no Firefox: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `M`

Comment: depois de imensos testes, para funcionar não posso usar o modal. Com o modal, nunca consegui obter o resultado que pretendia com esta solução e com outras que tentei testar de várias formas.